# Cannot change language through the Android emulator physical keyboard

Tags: android, android-studio, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, android-virtual-device

I have setup an Android API 30 emulator (from Android Studio), where I have installed two physical keyboard layouts. According to the system, I should be able to switch languages via Control+space. But that does not work.

I've tried:

- Changing the "send keyboard shortcuts" to "virtual device" - effectively disables multi-touch but that's it.
- Installed tons of different apps (including Hackers Keyboard) but saw no difference at all - seems they only work for the soft keyboard
- I tried changing the kcm keyboard file from open source projects (and it worked well for changing e.g. "a" to "9") but I could not make for instance Shift+space to execute a language switch fallback
- I even tried to write apps but I am not sure where to start (and from my experience with the other apps I tried, I am not sure if this will work at all)

Any ideas what else I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [Android x86](https://www.android-x86.org/). The control+space works there just fine.